# Does Octave support Live scripts or its format (.mlx) files?

Tags: octave

Matlab offers live scripts which enable its users to combine Matlab code , texts and images etc into single file format 
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/what-is-a-live-script-or-function.html

does Octave have any feature equivalent to this ?

Comment: You can use jupyter with an octave kernel, or the "publish" command from within octave to create dynamic documents, much like matlab's old 'publish' command. You can probably also use rmarkdown etc. You can also create an "interactive" script at octave-online.net and share the link. It depends what you're after exactly, really.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou I'm still beginner who wants to learn 
I'll take a Jupyter Tutorial and research into what you are saying and try to apply it since Jupyter is very common 
thank you very much

Comment: Such a shame that Octave does not directly have something comparable